# Make text blocks into dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a text file, contains hundreds of text blocks. And it contents like this:

```
product/productId: B001E4KFG0
review/userId: A3SGXH7AUHU8GW
review/profileName: delmartian
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1303862400
review/summary: Good Quality Dog Food
review/text: I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this product better than  most.

product/productId: B00813GRG4
review/userId: A1D87F6ZCVE5NK
review/profileName: dll pa
review/helpfulness: 0/0
review/score: 1.0
review/time: 1346976000
review/summary: Not as Advertised
review/text: Product arrived labeled as Jumbo Salted Peanuts...
```

I'm trying to convert this into `dictionary` like this

```
[{'product/productId': 'B001E4KFG0',
'review/userId': 'A3SGXH7AUHU8GW',
'review/profileName': 'delmartian',
'review/helpfulness': '1/1',
'review/score': 5.0,
'review/time': 1303862400,
'review/summary': 'Good Quality Dog Food',
'review/text': 'I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them \
all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better. \
My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this product better than  most.'},
{'product/productId': 'B00813GRG4',
'review/userId': 'A1D87F6ZCVE5NK',
'review/profileName': 'dll pa',
'review/helpfulness': '0/0',
'review/score': 1.0,
'review/time': 1346976000,
'review/summary': 'Not as Advertised',
'review/text': 'Product arrived labeled as Jumbo Salted Peanuts...the peanuts were actually \
small sized unsalted. Not sure if this was an error or if the vendor intended to represent the product as "Jumbo".'},...]
```

I have also examined a similar question asked in here and wrote the code in this way with help.

```
with open("foods.txt") as f:
        data = []
        blocks = [x. split('\n') for x in f.read().split('\n\n')]
        for line in blocks:
            data.append(
            dict([
            ("product/productId:" , line[0]),                 
            ("review/userId:", line[1]),                 
            ("review/profileName:", line[2]),
            ("review/helpfulness:", line[3]) ,  
            ("review/score:", line[4]),
            ("review/time:", line[5]),
            ("review/summary:", line[6]),
            ("review/text:", line[7])
            ]))
return data
```

However, I get the following error every time because of line[1],line[2]

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

Can anyone help with the reason? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following code:

```
with open("foods.txt") as f:
        data = []
        blocks = [x. split('\n') for x in f.read().split('\n\n')]
        for lines in blocks:
            d = {}
            for line in lines:
                key,val = line.split(":")
                d[key]=val
            data.append(d)
```

Below is the output:

[image: Here is the code with output]

Comment: You should paste the output here as text instead of a screenshot. Text is much more responsive to screen size changes and dark/light mode themes

Comment: I run the code I get  `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).` In some reviews the ":" sign is used more than once like this **review/text: I got a wild hair for taffy and ordered this five pound bag. The taffy was all very enjoyable with many flavors   :   watermelon, root beer, melon, peppermint, grape, etc.** . So I changed this line into  `key,val = line.split(":", maxsplit=1)`  but this time I'm getting `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. I think it's because there are spaces in the last lines of the file, but I'm not sure.   @user3503711

Comment: The empty lines would indeed fail. You could add `if line.count(':') == 0: continue` as a workaround to skip those lines.